# When a variable parameter is changed in a Rules loop, the variable is unchanged outside the loop

Tags: rules

I have a Rules loop in which a variable parameter is modified.
The variable was created before the loop, and added as parameter in the loop.

However, If I check the value of the variable after the loop, it is unchanged.

Is this by design or what causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example of a Rule (in Rules export format), which is a variation of what you're asking for:

```
{ "rules_show_list_of_fields" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show list of fields",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert" : [], "node_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "article" : "article" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "text", "value" : "StartOfList-" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "email_list" : "List of eMail IDs" } }
        }
      },
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "node:field-email-addresses" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "current_email" : "Current eMail" },
          "DO" : [
            { "data_set" : {
                "data" : [ "email-list" ],
                "value" : "[email-list:value][current-email:value]-"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "email-list" ], "value" : "[email-list:value]EndOfList" } },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "The value of the email_list variable is: [email-list:value]." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is a summary of what this rule does:

- Add a new variable `email_list`.
- Init the `email_list` value with some prefix.
- For each item within the loop, append the value of that item, followed by a separator character.
- Add a suffix to the `email_list` value.

In my case I'm using a multi value text field with machine name `field_email_addresses`, which contains eMail Ids, and just want to dispay a Status message with a concatenation of those eMail IDs, separated by a "`-`", and with a prefix (=`StartOfList`) / suffix (=`EndOfList`). And I also use Rules Events "Update existing node".

BTW, You could use this rule as a template to group multiple eMails (to individual eMail IDs) in a single eMail to all of those eMail IDs.

#### Demo

Here is how the Status message looks like after you create a new node, or update an existing node (of type Article):

> The value of the email_list variable is: StartOfList-user2@example.com-user4@example.com-EndOfList.

#### Conclusion

The variable was created before the loop, and modified in the loop.
And I display the value of the variable after the loop, it is changed like I wanted it to be changed.

As per what is shown in my answer here, it seems *something* is wrong in your rule (which you did not show in your question).

PS: I assume this question is about D7 ...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the conclusion of [Pierre.Vriens](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/39516/pierre-vriens). However, I have stumbled over a similar behavior as the OP.

If you alter the number of list items within the loop, the loop counter is not affected.

Example:

```
* List A contains three elements
* Loop the list
  * Remove one of the elements
* End loop
```

The loop will run three times, regardless of the change of the number of items in the list.